# Docker secret not working for MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD_FILE

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, docker-swarm

I'm learning about docker secrets to be used to store the mysql password for my lamp container stack. I am running docker for Windows 17.06.0-ce-win18 (12627).

I followed these steps:

1 - Created secret in docker as follows:

```
echo password | docker secret create mysql_db_root -
```

2 - Created the compose file shown below:

```
version: "3.1"
services:
  apachephp:
    image: apachephp
    deploy:
     replicas: 1
#     restart_policy:
 #      condition: on-failure
     resources:
       limits:
         cpus: "0.1"
         memory: 50M
    ports:
      - "80:80"
      - "443:443"
    volumes:
      - C:\Users\Daniel\Desktop\Learning\DockerStuff\phpdev\www:/var/www/html
    networks:
      - webnet
  db:
    image: mysql:latest
    ports:
      - "3306:3306"
    volumes:
      - C:\Users\Daniel\Desktop\Learning\DockerStuff\phpdev\db:/var/lib/mysql
    secrets:
      - mysql_db_root
    environment:
       MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD_FILE: /run/secrets/mysql_db_root
       #MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: "password"
    networks:
      - webnet
  adminer:
    image: adminer
    ports:
        - 8080:8080
    networks:
      - webnet
secrets:
  mysql_db_root:
    external: true
networks:
  webnet:
```

3 - Checked to ensure secret is available inside mysql container

```
C:\Learning\DockerStuff\phpdev>docker exec -it 452 bash
root@45278a63bc6b:/# cat /run/secrets/mysql_db_root
password
```

4 - So the password is available, now try to login to mysql:

```
root@45278a63bc6b:/# mysql
root@45278a63bc6b:/# mysql -u root -p -h localhost
Enter password:
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
```

And the password "password" does not work! Can anyonoe shed any light on this? Thanks in advance!

The mysql container log is below:

```
lampstack_db.1.wgofhqdl1v33@moby    | Initializing database
lampstack_db.1.wgofhqdl1v33@moby    | 2017-06-29T14:49:16.743604Z 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentation for more details).
lampstack_db.1.wgofhqdl1v33@moby    | 2017-06-29T14:49:17.468430Z 0 [Warning] InnoDB: New log files created, LSN=45790
lampstack_db.1.wgofhqdl1v33@moby    | 2017-06-29T14:49:17.563991Z 0 [Warning] InnoDB: Creating foreign key constraint system tables.
lampstack_db.1.wgofhqdl1v33@moby    | 2017-06-29T14:49:17.574436Z 0 [Warning] No existing UUID has been found, so we assume that this is the first time that this server has been started. Generating a new UUID: 207c7b19-5cda-11e7-854a-02420aff0004.
lampstack_db.1.wgofhqdl1v33@moby    | 2017-06-29T14:49:17.578567Z 0 [Warning] Gtid table is not ready to be used. Table 'mysql.gtid_executed' cannot be opened.
lampstack_db.1.wgofhqdl1v33@moby    | 2017-06-29T14:49:17.584520Z 1 [Warning] root@localhost is created with an empty password ! Please consider switching off the --initialize-insecure option.
lampstack_db.1.wgofhqdl1v33@moby    | 2017-06-29T14:49:20.354931Z 1 [Warning] 'user' entry 'root@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
lampstack_db.1.wgofhqdl1v33@moby    | 2017-06-29T14:49:20.354971Z 1 [Warning] 'user' entry 'mysql.sys@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
lampstack_db.1.wgofhqdl1v33@moby    | 2017-06-29T14:49:20.354980Z 1 [Warning] 'db' entry 'sys mysql.sys@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
lampstack_db.1.wgofhqdl1v33@moby    | 2017-06-29T14:49:20.354987Z 1 [Warning] 'proxies_priv' entry '@ root@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
lampstack_db.1.wgofhqdl1v33@moby    | 2017-06-29T14:49:20.355007Z 1 [Warning] 'tables_priv' entry 'sys_config mysql.sys@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
lampstack_db.1.wgofhqdl1v33@moby    | Database initialized
lampstack_db.1.wgofhqdl1v33@moby    | Initializing certificates
lampstack_db.1.wgofhqdl1v33@moby    | Generating a 2048 bit RSA private key
lampstack_db.1.wgofhqdl1v33@moby    | ..............................................................................................+++
lampstack_db.1.wgofhqdl1v33@moby    | ...............+++
lampstack_db.1.wgofhqdl1v33@moby    | unable to write 'random state'
lampstack_db.1.wgofhqdl1v33@moby    | writing new private key to 'ca-key.pem'
lampstack_db.1.wgofhqdl1v33@moby    | -----
lampstack_db.1.wgofhqdl1v33@moby    | Generating a 2048 bit RSA private key
lampstack_db.1.wgofhqdl1v33@moby    | ..............................+++
lampstack_db.1.wgofhqdl1v33@moby    | ..+++
lampstack_db.1.wgofhqdl1v33@moby    | unable to write 'random state'
lampstack_db.1.wgofhqdl1v33@moby    | writing new private key to 'server-key.pem'
lampstack_db.1.wgofhqdl1v33@moby    | -----
lampstack_db.1.wgofhqdl1v33@moby    | Generating a 2048 bit RSA private key
lampstack_db.1.wgofhqdl1v33@moby    | ............+++
lampstack_db.1.wgofhqdl1v33@moby    | .............+++
lampstack_db.1.wgofhqdl1v33@moby    | unable to write 'random state'
lampstack_db.1.wgofhqdl1v33@moby    | writing new private key to 'client-key.pem'
lampstack_db.1.wgofhqdl1v33@moby    | -----
lampstack_db.1.wgofhqdl1v33@moby    | Certificates initialized
lampstack_db.1.wgofhqdl1v33@moby    | MySQL init process in progress...
lampstack_db.1.wgofhqdl1v33@moby    | 2017-06-29T14:49:23.668312Z 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentation for more details).
lampstack_db.1.wgofhqdl1v33@moby    | 2017-06-29T14:49:23.674228Z 0 [Note] mysqld (mysqld 5.7.18) starting as process 89 ...
lampstack_db.1.wgofhqdl1v33@moby    | 2017-06-29T14:49:23.681123Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: PUNCH HOLE support available
lampstack_db.1.wgofhqdl1v33@moby    | 2017-06-29T14:49:23.681142Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
lampstack_db.1.wgofhqdl1v33@moby    | 2017-06-29T14:49:23.681145Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
lampstack_db.1.wgofhqdl1v33@moby    | 2017-06-29T14:49:23.681147Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: GCC builtin __atomic_thread_fence() is used for memory barrier
lampstack_db.1.wgofhqdl1v33@moby    | 2017-06-29T14:49:23.681149Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
lampstack_db.1.wgofhqdl1v33@moby    | 2017-06-29T14:49:23.681151Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
lampstack_db.1.wgofhqdl1v33@moby    | 2017-06-29T14:49:23.681304Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
lampstack_db.1.wgofhqdl1v33@moby    | 2017-06-29T14:49:23.681369Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using CPU crc32 instructions
lampstack_db.1.wgofhqdl1v33@moby    | 2017-06-29T14:49:23.682440Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 128M, instances = 1, chunk size = 128M
lampstack_db.1.wgofhqdl1v33@moby    | 2017-06-29T14:49:23.687878Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
lampstack_db.1.wgofhqdl1v33@moby    | 2017-06-29T14:49:23.689386Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: If the mysqld execution user is authorized, page cleaner thread priority can be changed. See the man page of setpriority().
lampstack_db.1.wgofhqdl1v33@moby    | 2017-06-29T14:49:23.721122Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
lampstack_db.1.wgofhqdl1v33@moby    | 2017-06-29T14:49:23.755720Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
lampstack_db.1.wgofhqdl1v33@moby    | 2017-06-29T14:49:23.756235Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file './ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
lampstack_db.1.wgofhqdl1v33@moby    | 2017-06-29T14:49:23.830478Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: File './ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.lampstack_db.1.wgofhqdl1v33@moby    | 2017-06-29T14:49:23.840143Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: 96 redo rollback segment(s) found. 96 redo rollback segment(s) are active.
lampstack_db.1.wgofhqdl1v33@moby    | 2017-06-29T14:49:23.840161Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: 32 non-redo rollback segment(s) are active.
lampstack_db.1.wgofhqdl1v33@moby    | 2017-06-29T14:49:23.840606Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
lampstack_db.1.wgofhqdl1v33@moby    | 2017-06-29T14:49:23.891432Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: 5.7.18 started; log sequence number 2535558
lampstack_db.1.wgofhqdl1v33@moby    | 2017-06-29T14:49:23.891977Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from /var/lib/mysql/ib_buffer_pool
lampstack_db.1.wgofhqdl1v33@moby    | 2017-06-29T14:49:23.892056Z 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
lampstack_db.1.wgofhqdl1v33@moby    | 2017-06-29T14:49:23.931384Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) load completed at 170629 14:49:23
lampstack_db.1.wgofhqdl1v33@moby    | 2017-06-29T14:49:23.934426Z 0 [Note] Found ca.pem, server-cert.pem and server-key.pem in data directory. Trying to enable SSL support using them.
lampstack_db.1.wgofhqdl1v33@moby    | 2017-06-29T14:49:23.936509Z 0 [Warning] CA certificate ca.pem is self signed.
lampstack_db.1.wgofhqdl1v33@moby    | 2017-06-29T14:49:23.952553Z 0 [Warning] 'user' entry 'root@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
lampstack_db.1.wgofhqdl1v33@moby    | 2017-06-29T14:49:23.952645Z 0 [Warning] 'user' entry 'mysql.sys@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
lampstack_db.1.wgofhqdl1v33@moby    | 2017-06-29T14:49:23.952829Z 0 [Warning] 'db' entry 'sys mysql.sys@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
lampstack_db.1.wgofhqdl1v33@moby    | 2017-06-29T14:49:23.953123Z 0 [Warning] 'proxies_priv' entry '@ root@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
lampstack_db.1.wgofhqdl1v33@moby    | 2017-06-29T14:49:23.976984Z 0 [Warning] 'tables_priv' entry 'sys_config mysql.sys@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
lampstack_db.1.wgofhqdl1v33@moby    | 2017-06-29T14:49:24.115430Z 0 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
lampstack_db.1.wgofhqdl1v33@moby    | 2017-06-29T14:49:24.115572Z 0 [Note] mysqld: ready for connections.
lampstack_db.1.wgofhqdl1v33@moby    | Version: '5.7.18'  socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 0  MySQL Community Server (GPL)
lampstack_db.1.wgofhqdl1v33@moby    | 2017-06-29T14:49:24.115578Z 0 [Note] Executing 'SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES;' to get a list of tables using the deprecated partition engine. You may use the startup option '--disable-partition-engine-check' to skip this check.
lampstack_db.1.wgofhqdl1v33@moby    | 2017-06-29T14:49:24.115580Z 0 [Note] Beginning of list of non-natively partitioned tables
lampstack_db.1.wgofhqdl1v33@moby    | 2017-06-29T14:49:24.235357Z 0 [Note] End of list of non-natively partitioned tables
lampstack_db.1.wgofhqdl1v33@moby    | Warning: Unable to load '/usr/share/zoneinfo/iso3166.tab' as time zone. Skipping it.
lampstack_db.1.wgofhqdl1v33@moby    | Warning: Unable to load '/usr/share/zoneinfo/leap-seconds.list' as time zone. Skipping it.
lampstack_db.1.wgofhqdl1v33@moby    | Warning: Unable to load '/usr/share/zoneinfo/zone.tab' as time zone. Skipping it.
lampstack_db.1.wgofhqdl1v33@moby    | 2017-06-29T14:49:26.307433Z 5 [Warning] 'user' entry 'root@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
lampstack_db.1.wgofhqdl1v33@moby    | 2017-06-29T14:49:26.307454Z 5 [Warning] 'user' entry 'mysql.sys@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
lampstack_db.1.wgofhqdl1v33@moby    | 2017-06-29T14:49:26.307466Z 5 [Warning] 'db' entry 'sys mysql.sys@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
lampstack_db.1.wgofhqdl1v33@moby    | 2017-06-29T14:49:26.307476Z 5 [Warning] 'proxies_priv' entry '@ root@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
lampstack_db.1.wgofhqdl1v33@moby    | 2017-06-29T14:49:26.307498Z 5 [Warning] 'tables_priv' entry 'sys_config mysql.sys@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
lampstack_db.1.wgofhqdl1v33@moby    |
lampstack_db.1.wgofhqdl1v33@moby    | 2017-06-29T14:49:26.308688Z 0 [Note] Giving 0 client threads a chance to die gracefully
lampstack_db.1.wgofhqdl1v33@moby    | 2017-06-29T14:49:26.308701Z 0 [Note] Shutting down slave threads
lampstack_db.1.wgofhqdl1v33@moby    | 2017-06-29T14:49:26.308704Z 0 [Note] Forcefully disconnecting 0 remaining clients
lampstack_db.1.wgofhqdl1v33@moby    | 2017-06-29T14:49:26.308706Z 0 [Note] Event Scheduler: Purging the queue. 0 events
lampstack_db.1.wgofhqdl1v33@moby    | 2017-06-29T14:49:26.308730Z 0 [Note] Binlog end
lampstack_db.1.wgofhqdl1v33@moby    | 2017-06-29T14:49:26.317357Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'ngram'
lampstack_db.1.wgofhqdl1v33@moby    | 2017-06-29T14:49:26.317377Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'BLACKHOLE'
lampstack_db.1.wgofhqdl1v33@moby    | 2017-06-29T14:49:26.317381Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'partition'
lampstack_db.1.wgofhqdl1v33@moby    | 2017-06-29T14:49:26.317383Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'ARCHIVE'
lampstack_db.1.wgofhqdl1v33@moby    | 2017-06-29T14:49:26.317385Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_VIRTUAL'
lampstack_db.1.wgofhqdl1v33@moby    | 2017-06-29T14:49:26.317387Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_DATAFILES'
lampstack_db.1.wgofhqdl1v33@moby    | 2017-06-29T14:49:26.317388Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_TABLESPACES'
lampstack_db.1.wgofhqdl1v33@moby    | 2017-06-29T14:49:26.317389Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_FOREIGN_COLS'
lampstack_db.1.wgofhqdl1v33@moby    | 2017-06-29T14:49:26.317391Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_FOREIGN'
lampstack_db.1.wgofhqdl1v33@moby    | 2017-06-29T14:49:26.317392Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_FIELDS'
lampstack_db.1.wgofhqdl1v33@moby    | 2017-06-29T14:49:26.317393Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_COLUMNS'
lampstack_db.1.wgofhqdl1v33@moby    | 2017-06-29T14:49:26.317394Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_INDEXES'
lampstack_db.1.wgofhqdl1v33@moby    | 2017-06-29T14:49:26.317395Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_TABLESTATS'
lampstack_db.1.wgofhqdl1v33@moby    | 2017-06-29T14:49:26.317397Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_SYS_TABLES'
lampstack_db.1.wgofhqdl1v33@moby    | 2017-06-29T14:49:26.317398Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_INDEX_TABLE'
lampstack_db.1.wgofhqdl1v33@moby    | 2017-06-29T14:49:26.317399Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_INDEX_CACHE'
lampstack_db.1.wgofhqdl1v33@moby    | 2017-06-29T14:49:26.317400Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_CONFIG'
lampstack_db.1.wgofhqdl1v33@moby    | 2017-06-29T14:49:26.317401Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_BEING_DELETED'
lampstack_db.1.wgofhqdl1v33@moby    | 2017-06-29T14:49:26.317403Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_DELETED'
lampstack_db.1.wgofhqdl1v33@moby    | 2017-06-29T14:49:26.317404Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_FT_DEFAULT_STOPWORD'
lampstack_db.1.wgofhqdl1v33@moby    | 2017-06-29T14:49:26.317405Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_METRICS'
lampstack_db.1.wgofhqdl1v33@moby    | 2017-06-29T14:49:26.317406Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_TEMP_TABLE_INFO'
lampstack_db.1.wgofhqdl1v33@moby    | 2017-06-29T14:49:26.317408Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_BUFFER_POOL_STATS'
lampstack_db.1.wgofhqdl1v33@moby    | 2017-06-29T14:49:26.317409Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_BUFFER_PAGE_LRU'
lampstack_db.1.wgofhqdl1v33@moby    | 2017-06-29T14:49:26.317410Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_BUFFER_PAGE'
lampstack_db.1.wgofhqdl1v33@moby    | 2017-06-29T14:49:26.317411Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP_PER_INDEX_RESET'
lampstack_db.1.wgofhqdl1v33@moby    | 2017-06-29T14:49:26.317412Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP_PER_INDEX'
lampstack_db.1.wgofhqdl1v33@moby    | 2017-06-29T14:49:26.317414Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMPMEM_RESET'lampstack_db.1.wgofhqdl1v33@moby    | 2017-06-29T14:49:26.317415Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMPMEM'
lampstack_db.1.wgofhqdl1v33@moby    | 2017-06-29T14:49:26.317417Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP_RESET'
lampstack_db.1.wgofhqdl1v33@moby    | 2017-06-29T14:49:26.317419Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_CMP'
lampstack_db.1.wgofhqdl1v33@moby    | 2017-06-29T14:49:26.317421Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_LOCK_WAITS'
lampstack_db.1.wgofhqdl1v33@moby    | 2017-06-29T14:49:26.317423Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_LOCKS'
lampstack_db.1.wgofhqdl1v33@moby    | 2017-06-29T14:49:26.317425Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'INNODB_TRX'
lampstack_db.1.wgofhqdl1v33@moby    | 2017-06-29T14:49:26.317427Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'InnoDB'
lampstack_db.1.wgofhqdl1v33@moby    | 2017-06-29T14:49:26.317486Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: FTS optimize thread exiting.
lampstack_db.1.wgofhqdl1v33@moby    | 2017-06-29T14:49:26.317588Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
lampstack_db.1.wgofhqdl1v33@moby    | 2017-06-29T14:49:26.418806Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Dumping buffer pool(s) to /var/lib/mysql/ib_buffer_pool
lampstack_db.1.wgofhqdl1v33@moby    | 2017-06-29T14:49:26.428161Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) dump completed at 170629 14:49:26
lampstack_db.1.wgofhqdl1v33@moby    | 2017-06-29T14:49:27.856347Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Shutdown completed; log sequence number 12139694
lampstack_db.1.wgofhqdl1v33@moby    | 2017-06-29T14:49:27.859197Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Removed temporary tablespace data file: "ibtmp1"
lampstack_db.1.wgofhqdl1v33@moby    | 2017-06-29T14:49:27.859225Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'MRG_MYISAM'
lampstack_db.1.wgofhqdl1v33@moby    | 2017-06-29T14:49:27.859229Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'MyISAM'
lampstack_db.1.wgofhqdl1v33@moby    | 2017-06-29T14:49:27.859239Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'CSV'
lampstack_db.1.wgofhqdl1v33@moby    | 2017-06-29T14:49:27.859280Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'MEMORY'
lampstack_db.1.wgofhqdl1v33@moby    | 2017-06-29T14:49:27.859282Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'PERFORMANCE_SCHEMA'
lampstack_db.1.wgofhqdl1v33@moby    | 2017-06-29T14:49:27.859306Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'sha256_password'
lampstack_db.1.wgofhqdl1v33@moby    | 2017-06-29T14:49:27.859312Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'mysql_native_password'
lampstack_db.1.wgofhqdl1v33@moby    | 2017-06-29T14:49:27.859446Z 0 [Note] Shutting down plugin 'binlog'
lampstack_db.1.wgofhqdl1v33@moby    | 2017-06-29T14:49:27.860931Z 0 [Note] mysqld: Shutdown complete
lampstack_db.1.wgofhqdl1v33@moby    |
lampstack_db.1.wgofhqdl1v33@moby    |
lampstack_db.1.wgofhqdl1v33@moby    | MySQL init process done. Ready for start up.
lampstack_db.1.wgofhqdl1v33@moby    |
lampstack_db.1.wgofhqdl1v33@moby    | 2017-06-29T14:49:28.121719Z 0 [Warning] TIMESTAMP with implicit DEFAULT value is deprecated. Please use --explicit_defaults_for_timestamp server option (see documentation for more details).
lampstack_db.1.wgofhqdl1v33@moby    | 2017-06-29T14:49:28.126586Z 0 [Note] mysqld (mysqld 5.7.18) starting as process 1 ...
lampstack_db.1.wgofhqdl1v33@moby    | 2017-06-29T14:49:28.134269Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: PUNCH HOLE support available
lampstack_db.1.wgofhqdl1v33@moby    | 2017-06-29T14:49:28.134297Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Mutexes and rw_locks use GCC atomic builtins
lampstack_db.1.wgofhqdl1v33@moby    | 2017-06-29T14:49:28.134301Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Uses event mutexes
lampstack_db.1.wgofhqdl1v33@moby    | 2017-06-29T14:49:28.134303Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: GCC builtin __atomic_thread_fence() is used for memory barrier
lampstack_db.1.wgofhqdl1v33@moby    | 2017-06-29T14:49:28.134305Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Compressed tables use zlib 1.2.3
lampstack_db.1.wgofhqdl1v33@moby    | 2017-06-29T14:49:28.134306Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using Linux native AIO
lampstack_db.1.wgofhqdl1v33@moby    | 2017-06-29T14:49:28.134586Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Number of pools: 1
lampstack_db.1.wgofhqdl1v33@moby    | 2017-06-29T14:49:28.134962Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Using CPU crc32 instructions
lampstack_db.1.wgofhqdl1v33@moby    | 2017-06-29T14:49:28.136240Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Initializing buffer pool, total size = 128M, instances = 1, chunk size = 128M
lampstack_db.1.wgofhqdl1v33@moby    | 2017-06-29T14:49:28.142101Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Completed initialization of buffer pool
lampstack_db.1.wgofhqdl1v33@moby    | 2017-06-29T14:49:28.143292Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: If the mysqld execution user is authorized, page cleaner thread priority can be changed. See the man page of setpriority().
lampstack_db.1.wgofhqdl1v33@moby    | 2017-06-29T14:49:28.183384Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Highest supported file format is Barracuda.
lampstack_db.1.wgofhqdl1v33@moby    | 2017-06-29T14:49:28.242543Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Creating shared tablespace for temporary tables
lampstack_db.1.wgofhqdl1v33@moby    | 2017-06-29T14:49:28.242892Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Setting file './ibtmp1' size to 12 MB. Physically writing the file full; Please wait ...
lampstack_db.1.wgofhqdl1v33@moby    | 2017-06-29T14:49:28.310986Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: File './ibtmp1' size is now 12 MB.lampstack_db.1.wgofhqdl1v33@moby    | 2017-06-29T14:49:28.317119Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: 96 redo rollback segment(s) found. 96 redo rollback segment(s) are active.
lampstack_db.1.wgofhqdl1v33@moby    | 2017-06-29T14:49:28.317140Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: 32 non-redo rollback segment(s) are active.
lampstack_db.1.wgofhqdl1v33@moby    | 2017-06-29T14:49:28.317361Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Waiting for purge to start
lampstack_db.1.wgofhqdl1v33@moby    | 2017-06-29T14:49:28.367892Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: 5.7.18 started; log sequence number 12139694
lampstack_db.1.wgofhqdl1v33@moby    | 2017-06-29T14:49:28.368297Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Loading buffer pool(s) from /var/lib/mysql/ib_buffer_pool
lampstack_db.1.wgofhqdl1v33@moby    | 2017-06-29T14:49:28.368339Z 0 [Note] Plugin 'FEDERATED' is disabled.
lampstack_db.1.wgofhqdl1v33@moby    | 2017-06-29T14:49:28.396380Z 0 [Note] Found ca.pem, server-cert.pem and server-key.pem in data directory. Trying to enable SSL support using them.
lampstack_db.1.wgofhqdl1v33@moby    | 2017-06-29T14:49:28.406576Z 0 [Warning] CA certificate ca.pem is self signed.
lampstack_db.1.wgofhqdl1v33@moby    | 2017-06-29T14:49:28.408554Z 0 [Note] Server hostname (bind-address): '*'; port: 3306
lampstack_db.1.wgofhqdl1v33@moby    | 2017-06-29T14:49:28.408580Z 0 [Note] IPv6 is available.
lampstack_db.1.wgofhqdl1v33@moby    | 2017-06-29T14:49:28.408586Z 0 [Note]   - '::' resolves to '::';
lampstack_db.1.wgofhqdl1v33@moby    | 2017-06-29T14:49:28.408598Z 0 [Note] Server socket created on IP: '::'.
lampstack_db.1.wgofhqdl1v33@moby    | 2017-06-29T14:49:28.409911Z 0 [Note] InnoDB: Buffer pool(s) load completed at 170629 14:49:28
lampstack_db.1.wgofhqdl1v33@moby    | 2017-06-29T14:49:28.423707Z 0 [Warning] 'user' entry 'root@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
lampstack_db.1.wgofhqdl1v33@moby    | 2017-06-29T14:49:28.423739Z 0 [Warning] 'user' entry 'mysql.sys@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
lampstack_db.1.wgofhqdl1v33@moby    | 2017-06-29T14:49:28.423871Z 0 [Warning] 'db' entry 'sys mysql.sys@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
lampstack_db.1.wgofhqdl1v33@moby    | 2017-06-29T14:49:28.424004Z 0 [Warning] 'proxies_priv' entry '@ root@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
lampstack_db.1.wgofhqdl1v33@moby    | 2017-06-29T14:49:28.442753Z 0 [Warning] 'tables_priv' entry 'sys_config mysql.sys@localhost' ignored in --skip-name-resolve mode.
lampstack_db.1.wgofhqdl1v33@moby    | 2017-06-29T14:49:28.524101Z 0 [Note] Event Scheduler: Loaded 0 events
lampstack_db.1.wgofhqdl1v33@moby    | 2017-06-29T14:49:28.524336Z 0 [Note] mysqld: ready for connections.
lampstack_db.1.wgofhqdl1v33@moby    | Version: '5.7.18'  socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server (GPL)
lampstack_db.1.wgofhqdl1v33@moby    | 2017-06-29T14:49:28.524369Z 0 [Note] Executing 'SELECT * FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES;' to get a list of tables using the deprecated partition engine. You may use the startup option '--disable-partition-engine-check' to skip this check.
lampstack_db.1.wgofhqdl1v33@moby    | 2017-06-29T14:49:28.524372Z 0 [Note] Beginning of list of non-natively partitioned tables
lampstack_db.1.wgofhqdl1v33@moby    | 2017-06-29T14:49:28.641848Z 0 [Note] End of list of non-natively partitioned tables
```

Comment: Can you outline the commands used to reproduce? When I run under Compose I get `WARNING: Service "db" uses secret "mysql_db_root" which is external. External secrets are not available to containers created by docker-compose.` and `/run/secrets` is empty. But if I create the service manually with `docker service create` it does run as intended and the password works.

Comment: docker stack deploy -c docker-compose.yml lampstack

Comment: When I run the example I get `Rejected 2 seconds ago    "invalid mount config for type…"`. If I modify the `docker-compose.yml` to include a new volume called `db` and then mount the volume as `db:/var/lib/mysql` it does work. It sounds like maybe your deploy has changed a bit and has some carryover from initial deployment that may have had another password? Once you provision the password for the `/var/lib/mysql` mount it will persist, so changing it would not change the password (you have to remove the volume and re-deploy).

Comment: Andy, thanks for the comment. I thought about that... I know once you deploy once successfully, the password is stored in the sql db, and is no longer read from the docker secret. I tried to take care of that by flushing the mounted volume each time I removed the stack and redeployed.

Comment: Hmm, if you have tried removing the DB folder and the services already then I am not quite sure where to go next. Unfortunately, it is working as desired for me.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same issue running linux containers on a windows machine when I created the secret inline.

> echo mypassword | docker secret create mysql_db_root -

The actual password gets saved with a space, carriage return, and new line at the end. This can be seen if you look at the bytes in the file. In the running mysql container you can use the od command like the following example below to view the bytes. Or outside the container you can dump the /run/secrets/mysql_db_root content to a file and view with your favorite hex editor on windows to see the added bytes.

> od -xa /run/secrets/mysql_db_root

To resolve the issue create the secret by putting it in a file and then using the file to generate the docker secret. See the [mysql github issue](https://github.com/docker-library/mysql/issues/501#issuecomment-427443301) for more details.

> docker secret create mysql_db_root mypasswordfile.txt